What is the correct way to unpack a tuple composed of a TreeNode and an Integer?
I'm implementing an algorithm that requires appending and popping nodes from a Tree in python (in a FIFO way).
queue = []  # empty list
root = TreeNode()  # a standard TreeNode with val, left and right

I'm trying to store both root and an integer in the queue:
queue.append((root,0))

...
and then trying to pop it:
n,l = queue.pop(0)

Now, I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable TreeNode object
    ^^^
    n,l = queue.pop(0)

I tested if I could append and pop just the root node and it seems to work. The problem is the inclusion of the integer so I'm assuming my syntax is incorrect. I also tried:
queue.append(((root,0)))
queue.append(Tuple((root,0)))
queue.append([(root,0)])  # that one gave me ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

None of them seems to work.
Can you provide any help in this matter?
Update: As requested below, here's the code portion:
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
        queue = []  # far slower than 'deque' but should work
        
        if not root:
            return queue

        queue.append((root,0))
        levels={}
        while queue:
            n,l = queue.pop(0)
            if n:
                if l not in levels:
                    levels[l] = []
                levels[l].append(n.val)
                queue.append(n.left)
                queue.append(n.right)

        return [[]]

Full error:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable TreeNode object
    ^^^
    n,l = queue.pop(0)
Line 17 in levelOrder (Solution.py)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ret = Solution().levelOrder(param_1)
Line 45 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 56 in <module> (Solution.py)


The simplified code in your question (and the syntax to unpack a tuple from the queue) basically works, so the issue is elsewhere:
class TreeNode:
    pass


queue = []
root = TreeNode()

queue.append((root, 0))  # A tuple.
n, l = queue.pop(0)  # Works.

queue.append(root)  # Just a node, not a tuple.
n, l = queue.pop(0)  # Doesn't.


In the full tree-traversing code, there's
queue.append(n.left)
queue.append(n.right)

which are putting just nodes (which aren't unpackable) into your queue.
I think you mean
queue.append((n.left, l))
queue.append((n.right, l))

there.



# Assume TreeNode is a class defined as follows
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

# Example tuple containing a TreeNode and an Integer
node_and_value = (TreeNode(1), 10)

# Unpacking the tuple
node, value = node_and_value

# Accessing the unpacked values
print("TreeNode value:", node.value)
print("Integer value:", value)




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value=29, left=0.0004, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


queue = []

root = TreeNode()
queue.append((root, 0.7))

n, l = queue.pop(0)

print(n.value, n.left, n.right, l)

